# Aligning rotated xticklabels and ylabels with their respective xticks and yticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Here is the output of the code :

```
array = [[64,7,5],
         [9,195,1],
         [6,17,2]]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, range(3), range(3))

sn.set(font_scale=1.4) # for l)abel size

sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}, cmap='Blues', fmt='g') # font size
class_names = ['dog','cat','bear']

plt.gca().xaxis.tick_top()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_label_position('top')
 
tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names, rotation=45, rotation_mode='anchor')
plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names, rotation='horizontal')# rotation='horizontal', ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor'
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label',size=14)
plt.xlabel('Predicted label',size=14)

plt.show()
```

I would like to align labels of x and y with center position, So please how can I change the above

[image: my_output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))` you're setting new tick marks. Just get the existing ones with `ax.get_xticks()`/`ax.get_yticks()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn

array = [[64,7,5],
         [9,195,1],
         [6,17,2]]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, range(3), range(3))

sn.set(font_scale=1.4) # for l)abel size

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot_kws={"size": 16}, cmap='Blues', fmt='g') # font size
class_names = ['dog','cat','bear']

plt.gca().xaxis.tick_top()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_label_position('top')
 
plt.xticks(ax.get_xticks(), class_names, rotation=45, rotation_mode='anchor')
plt.yticks(ax.get_yticks(), class_names, rotation='horizontal')# rotation='horizontal', ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor'
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label',size=14)
plt.xlabel('Predicted label',size=14)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: you'll achieve the same result by replacing your `plt.xticks(...)` and `plt.yticks(...)` with the following:

```
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(class_names, rotation=45, rotation_mode='anchor')
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(class_names, rotation='horizontal')
```